# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'y' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#F(x;y) = a · x + b · y
def F1(a, b):
    x = np.linspace(-6,9,100)
    y = a*x + b
    return x, y

#F(x; y) = a · x - b · y
def F2(a, b):
    x = np.linspace(-6,9,100)
    y = a*x - b
    return x, y

#F(x; y) = a · x · b · y
def F3(a, b):
    x = np.linspace(-6,9,100)
    y = a*x*b
    return x, y

#F(x; y) = (a · x) / (b · y)
def F4(a, b):
    x = np.linspace(-6,9,100)
    y = (a*x)/(b*y)
    return x, y

plt.title("Euler's method")
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")

a = 5
b = 1

x, y = F1(a, b)
plt.plot(x, y, label="F1(x,y): a · x + b · y")

x, y = F2(a, b)
plt.plot(x, y, label="F2(x,y): a · x - b · y")

x, y = F3(a, b)
plt.plot(x, y, label="F3(x,y): a · x · b · y")

x, y = F4(a, b)
plt.plot(x, y, label="F4(x,y): (a · x) / (b · y)")


plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I am receiving the following error in Python (I'm using Jupyter):

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'y' referenced before assignment

in line 25 and 44

25 line y = (a*x)/(b*y)

44 line x, y = F4(a, b)
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Where is `y` coming from in `F4`?

Comment: To elaborate: `y = (a*x)/(b*y)` ok, but the RHS has `y` and it's not defined

Comment: if you want to use the "outside" `y` that was previously calculated in `F3` for calculation inside `F4`, you have to pass that variable as a parameter as well.

Comment: If it's like all the other functions, that should probably be `y = (a*x)/b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your F4 function you need to change your equation to get y value .. You can not have y on right hand side before assigning value to it.

```
def F4(a, b):
    x = np.linspace(-6,9,100)
    y = (a*x)/(b)
    return x, y
```